# Who coined the term Bantustan for the first time and why did they use the Persian suffix?

Tags: africa, terminology, south-africa

From the Wikipedia article for [Bantustan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bantustan):

> The term, first used in the late 1940s, was coined from Bantu (meaning "people" in some of the Bantu languages) and -stan (a suffix meaning "land" in the Persian language and some Persian-influenced languages of western, central, and southern Asia).

But neither the Wikipedia entry nor the provided source ([OED](https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?q=Bantustan&tl=true)) mentioned who coined the term for the first time.

Also, what was the reason they used a Persian suffix?

Comment: [ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=+Bantustan&year_start=1967&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) may be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably first "Bantu Hindustan" by J.S. Franklin, then shortened either by him or others to "Bantustan":

J.S. Franklin ([1949](https://dsae.co.za/entry/bantustan/e00570)):

> back of and beyond our Bantu Hindustan there lies the Continent of Africa with its 250 millions of black-skinned people.

Edgar Brookes ([June 1949](https://books.google.com/books?id=cptdBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA93)):

> a great Bantu State or group of States to which at least one ingenious thinker has affixed the term 'Bantustan'

E.H. Brookes ([1949](https://books.google.com/books?id=fhwUAAAAIAAJ&q=bantustan))

> the creation of a new large Bantu state. Some speakers have referred to it as 'Bantustan'.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=p46yBRqVSXgC&q=bantustan&dq=bantustan&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje38zJ4v-BAxW_GVkFHYuKCuYQ6AF6BAgLEAI shows a 1947 use

Comment: @kimchilover: That is interesting. That seems to be a very isolated use of Bantustan in the context of Uganda, not related to subsequent and more common uses of Bantustan in the context of South Africa. // *Possibly no state in Panafrica has a greater variety of tourismatic attractions to offer than Bantustan* - I'm not sure what "Bantustan" refers to. // There is a reference to a "Central Bantustan University", but I have been unable to find any information on the existence of any such university.

Comment: I _think_ the publication I found was a student literary or humor magazine at Makerere College (now Uni) in Uganda, and that in it "Bantustan" means "Uganda", in a tongue-in-cheek speculation about what the future might bring.  I agree that this is not the Bantustan of Nationalist South Africa.

Comment: Continuing: I think "Central Bantustan University" means "Makerere University" in this article.

Comment: Why did they use Hindustan to make the term? Why not other -stan words?

Comment: I've updated the question